# Not getting the correct position after filter in listview using SimpleAddapter

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, simpleadapter

creating a arraylist

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
```

add simpleAddapter to display 4 fielsd 
now i want to search an item in list so i have used

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        ((SimpleAdapter)getListAdapter()).getFilter().filter(s); 
                        }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

it filter the listView properly but when i try to access listview item then it will not return the correct position i.e if two items are display after file the position is same as the old list item ..
so how to get the correct data from onListItemClick ??

Comment: it would be better if you mentioned the type instead of object in hashmap <HashMap<String,Object>> . instead of Object mention what type it is (String,Integer..);

Comment: i dont have issue in getting the position i am also using the same  ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.position2)).setText(list.get(position).get(Constants.contactname).toString());
problem is that after filter the list not getting the correct position i.e if two items are display after file and i m getting data from that list item it will not display which is selected .  it will display the items arrange in previous listview.

Comment: you need to override listview item click you will get the position using position parameter of item Click method. i don't know how to put this in a better way. may be some one can explain it you better

Comment: when you filter you should also call notifydatasetchanged() on your adapter to refresh listview

Comment: can any buddy help me in this situation @............http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606766/search-item-in-edittext-from-listview-showing-wrong-result

Answer (score 0):

Send your filtered ArrayList to your custom adapter , initialize it in it's constructor then use your ArrayList in getItem() function of your adapter like :

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position).get("key");
}
```

Comment: its a arraylist of map. it should be list.get(position).get("key");

Comment: i dont have issue in getting the position i am also using the same  ((TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.position2)).setText(list.get(position).get(Constants.contactname).toString());
problem is that after filter the list not getting the correct position i.e if two items are display after file and i m getting data from that list item it will not display which is selected .  it will display the items arrange in previous listview.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                //abrirActividadDetallada(position, id);
                Object MyObject=(Object) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                CustomMethod(MyObject);
            }
        });
```

Comment: The OP did not ask for an `OnItemClickListener`. He wanted to filter entries. Additionally, please focus on more current questions, this one is nearly 2 years old.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #get actual position of list after filter listview
    1.
      @Override// use in adapter
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return list.get(position).getID();
        }
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(“actual position”,String.valueof((int)id))
                }enter code here
            });
```