# Search item in edittext from listview showing wrong result

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, addtextchangedlistener

Trying to search a listview items using edittext, where clicking on searched item returning wrong position.

Supposed i search "C" from given list where list item is as follows "A","B","C","D","CC", and got the correct search result but once making the click on search item, It returning the wrong item position.

Here Edittext addTextChangedListener :

```
edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }
```

> **Complete class code:**

```
    package com.tomar.xyz;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Tabtwo extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    TextView txt;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText edtSearch;

    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] { "Admin Cost", "Affinity Diagram",
            "Analyse", "Apprasal Costs", "Assessment of Stakeholders",
              };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[] { R.drawable.admin, R.drawable.affinity,
            R.drawable.analysis, R.drawable.appraisal, R.drawable.assessment,
              };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabtwo);

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hm.put("txt", countries[i]);

            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]));
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag", "txt" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag, R.id.txt };

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        edtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Search_box);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admincost.class);
            startActivity(int0);
        }

        if (position == 1) {
            Intent int1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Affinity.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        }
        if (position == 2) {
            Intent int2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Analyse.class);
            startActivity(int2);
        }

        if (position == 3) {
            Intent int3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ApprasalCosts.class);
            startActivity(int3);
        }
        if (position == 4) {
            Intent int1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Assessment.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        } }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must need to clear your arraylist having data, and just fill them where u r filtering the listview.

Comment: see my answer below, hope it will help you.

Comment: show us list on item click listener

Comment: @vipul, i have added the complete code.

Comment: Check this link - i think helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737009/how-to-make-a-nice-looking-listview-filter-on-android

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code :-

```
@Override
                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     ArrayList<String> STOREID_SUB = new ArrayList<String>();
                     ArrayList<String> STORE_NAME_SUB = new ArrayList<String>();
                     ArrayList<String> PHOTO_SUB = new ArrayList<String>();
                     ArrayList<String> PLACE_STATUS_SUB = new ArrayList<String>();
                     final ArrayList<String> STORE_DESC_SUB = new ArrayList<String>();

                     textlength = searchText.getText().length();

                     for (int i = 0; i < STORE_NAME.size(); i++)
                     {
                         if (textlength <= STORE_NAME.get(i).length())
                         {
                             if (searchText.getText().toString().
                                     equalsIgnoreCase((String) STORE_NAME.get(i).subSequence(0, textlength)))
                             {
                                 STORE_NAME_SUB.add(STORE_NAME.get(i));
                                 STOREID_SUB.add(STOREID.get(i));
                                 PHOTO_SUB.add(PHOTO.get(i));
                                 STORE_DESC_SUB.add(STORE_DESC.get(i));
                                 PLACE_STATUS_SUB.add(PLACE_STATUS.get(i));


                             }
                         }
                     }

                     adapter=new StoreSearchListAdapter(context, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, STORE_NAME_SUB, PHOTO_SUB,STORE_DESC_SUB,PLACE_STATUS_SUB);
                     singlePlaceChooserList.setAdapter(adapter);



         }
```

here i am creating a new arraylist inside onTextCahnged method, and then using these values to set my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Change your onItemClick to:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method 

        if (((String)adapter.getItem(position)).equals("Admin Cost")) {
            Intent int0 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Admincost.class);
            startActivity(int0);
        }
          .........................

    }
```

When you filter your list, items get rearranged and thier position change so navigate to next activity based on the value on that position instead of position.

Comment: I am guessing this string returns the country name selected. If that's true this will work. If not try printing that value and find out what does it return.

Comment: Now my app crash, on filter item click for new answer.

Comment: thnks for your answer, Now I have resolved my problem. see the code in my answer.